# Writing an Antlr parser for the first time

Tags: parsing, antlr

Need a bit of help understanding how to write the first rules for my antlr parser, i've found this reference grammar to write one and i'm beginning to go down the list:

[image]

So far my understanding is that I have to use my decaf parser token types and makes the above rules in the format of:

```
type: 
statement:
assign_op:
method_call:
```

etc

I've managed to write the first rule I think below:

```
type: (TK_int) | TK_boolean);
```

can anybody explain how I can go about filling in the rest so that I understand what is actually happening in my parser? any help is appreciated, thanks

edit - just managed to figure out assign_op

```
assign_op: assign | plus_assign_op | minus assign op
```

Comment: The `<...>` are parser rules, the bold words and character between quotes are lexer rules. If you have more specific questions, feel free to edit your post and ask. Make sure to post your grammar as well.

Comment: What Antlr documentation/resources are you using?  There is the "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" at the Pragmatic Bookshelf, which is probably your best bet for a quick start.  It has a walk-through of an example grammar "Cymbol.g4" that is quite similar to your reference spec.